# How to print in PHP data retrieved from SQL that has been saved with single quote

Tags: php, html, sql, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have some used saved data in SQL that has single quotes in the name (for instance, Marco D'Alba. Via php, I'm printing these names on my website, but SQL will save that name like this:

> Marco D\'Angelo.

When I print these names, 
`Marco D\'Angelo` gets printed.

Any easy fixes?

Comment: use `mysql_real_escape_string()` OR `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function for that.

Comment: Use prepared statements / parametrised queries. That is all. :P

Comment: Please elaborate on `but SQL will save that name like this`.

Comment: SQL isn't saving the names like that, you have some bad code somewhere that is escaping the quotes too many times. Step One is to fix your inserts to use prepared statements so you don't have to manually escape your strings.

Answer (score 0):

Please print it like this:

```
$text = "Marco D'Alba";
echo mysql_real_escape_string($text);
```

The mysql_real_escape_string() function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

```
$text = "Marco D'Alba";
echo mysqli_real_escape_string($text);
```

If magic_quotes_runtime is enabled, most functions that return data from any sort of external source including databases and text files will have quotes escaped with a backslash. If magic_quotes_sybase is also on, a single-quote is escaped with a single-quote instead of a backslash.

You have to check and set "magic_quotes_runtime" and  "magic_quotes_sybase" in your php.ini

Comment: I am already using mysql_real_escape_string when the user inserts his name.
    $value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Surname']);
The database still saves it as Mauro D'\Alba! So when I go print it (even using mysqlrealescapestring when I print, it will still print the single quote!

Comment: I have modified my answer. Please check "magic_quotes_runtime" and "magic_quotes_sybase" in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print and get rid of the single quote, try using

```
echo stripslashes("Marco D\'Angelo");
```